# UWP custom TextBox styling

Tags: uwp

I'm currently working on a restyle of an existing UWP project where a couple of `TextBox` controls need to be implemented slightly different than before. The Header property should be shown inside the `TextBox` and there should be a couple of other, small tweaks like `CornerRadius` etc. This should be relatively easy (or so I thought). With my (admittedly, slightly limited) experience on UWP styling, after some searching, I came to the conclusion that my best MO would be to create a new style targeting `TextBox` so that I could specify which box would behave that way and leave the rest as is.

I have created a custom style, in which the `BorderElement` starts on row 0 and spans 2 rows to surround both header and input text by copying the template for `TextBox` from the generic XAML file. It looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="InlineHeaderTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ControlText}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlBorder}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MS-SemiBold}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12 6 12 6" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Green">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Visibility="Visible" Opacity="1"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}">

                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>

                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>

                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                    To="0"
                                                                    Duration="0" />
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    FontStyle="Normal"
                                                    FontSize="12"
                                                    Text="&#xE10A;"
                                                    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">                                    
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                            FontWeight="Normal"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource ControlTextLight}"
                            Background="Red"
                            Margin="12 6 12 6"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Visibility="Visible"
                            Opacity="1" 
                            x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                            MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"
                            MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                            IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                            IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                            TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
                            TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            MinWidth="34"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The text box is implemented as follows on a relative panel:

```
<TextBox Name="test1" Text="1234" Style="{StaticResource InlineHeaderTextBox}" PlaceholderText="test placeholder text" Header="test header text" InputScope="Digits" MaxLength="10" Width="200" RelativePanel.Below="P3R3C1" />
<TextBox Name="test2" Text="5678" PlaceholderText="test placeholder text" Header="test header text" InputScope="Digits" MaxLength="10" Width="200" RelativePanel.Below="test1" />
```

The result looks good, but the header text and its background look slightly lighter than expected (faded), and disappear when the textbox is focused!

[image: textbox with faded header text that disappears on focus]

For reference, I added a 2nd textbox below it without any styling. For this box, the header text looks unfaded and remains static, even when focusing the box. I've tried fiddling with the VisualStates and using a custom HeaderTemplate, even added Red and Green backgrounds to see what happens to the header text, but can't seem to work out what causes the header text that uses my custom style behave this way.

How can I style this header to remain even when focused, and show clear (not slightly faded) like the second textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `BorderElement` which is above the `HeaderContentPresenter` in the template. By default, it is only partially opaque, but enough to make your header look faded. When focused, its background is set to fully opaque so your header disappears.

To fix this, it should be enough to switch move the `BorderElement` above `HeaderContentPresenter` in the template:

```xml
...
<Border x:Name="BorderElement"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="1"
    CornerRadius="4"
    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
    MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"
    MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
<ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
    FontWeight="Normal"
    Foreground="{StaticResource ControlTextLight}"
    Background="Red"
    Margin="12 6 12 6"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Visibility="Visible"
    Opacity="1" 
    x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
...
```